# UIPickerView is not populating

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

Hails,

I'm challenging to write clean code. Therefore i want to keep my datasource and deletegate in seperate class files and extensions. So want to keep closer to M-V-C style. Therefore my model is seperated from all my controller classes and view classes. But there is a problem with populating the pickerView object. Here is the code;

//My Delegate and Datasource
    import Foundation
    import UIKit

```
class MyPickerView: NSObject{
var data = PickerViewData.getData()



}
extension MyPickerView: UIPickerViewDataSource{
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return self.data.count
}    
}

extension MyPickerView: UIPickerViewDelegate{
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent 
component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, 
forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    let dayLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 100, height: 15))
    let priceLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    let petLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 78, width: 100, height: 15))
    dayLbl.text = data[row].dayName
    priceLbl.text = String(data[row].price)
    petLbl.text = data[row].petName

    dayLbl.textAlignment = .center
    priceLbl.textAlignment = .center
    petLbl.textAlignment = .center
    view.addSubview(dayLbl)
    view.addSubview(priceLbl)
    view.addSubview(petLbl)
    return view
}
```

}

//My Model

```
import Foundation

struct PickerViewModel{
var dayName:String!
var price:Double!
var petName:String!
init(dayName:String,price:Double,petName:String) {
    self.dayName = dayName
    self.price = price
    self.petName = petName
}

}
struct PickerViewData {
static func getData() -> [PickerViewModel]{
    let m = PickerViewModel(dayName: "Pazartesi", price: 32.3, 
petName: "Köpek")
    let p = PickerViewModel(dayName: "Salı", price: 32.3, petName: 
"Kuş")
    let z = PickerViewModel(dayName: "Çarşamba", price: 32.3, 
petName: "Kedi")
    let t = PickerViewModel(dayName: "Perşembe", price: 32.3, 
petName: "Domuz")
    let k = PickerViewModel(dayName: "Cuma", price: 32.3, petName: 
"Kanarya")
    return [m,p,z,t,k]
}
}
```

//My Controller

```
import UIKit

class FirstVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, 
width: 200, height: 500))
    let deldat = MyPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = deldat
    pickerView.dataSource = deldat
    self.view.addSubview(pickerView)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}    

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The picker view's `dataSource` and `delegate` properties are declared as `weak` - this means that they don't retain your `MyPickerView` instance. Since your instance is a local variable, as soon as `viewDidLoad` exits, it will be released.

You need to hold your `MyPickerView` instance in an instance property, so that it is retained for the lifetime of your view controller:

```
import UIKit

class FirstVC: UIViewController {

    private var deldat: MyPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, 
width: 200, height: 500))
        self.deldat = MyPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = deldat
        pickerView.dataSource = deldat
        self.view.addSubview(pickerView)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct! I missed up the detail that is about weakness of the datasource and delegate. So furthermore, i'm not going to use the datasource and delegate instances as local var. Since i know the weak keyword is about memory performance, so would you explain that why is datasource and delegate vars are declared as weak?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Declaring them as `weak` helps prevent retain cycles.  Your view controller holds a strong reference to the picker view (via its `view` property).  If the datasource/delegate weren't weak then the picker view would be holding a strong reference back to the view controller.  This would mean that if the view controller  was otherwise free to be released (ie. nothing else was using it), it would still remain in memory as a "leak" because of the circular strong references unless you specifically set delegate/datasource to `nil`.  By making the delegate/datasource weak this won't occur.

Comment: Your explanation is perfect and i understood properly. Memory leak issue is an important issue even the iPhones does not includes lots of gigs of memory. So for not facing with the didReceiveMemoryWarning function call, i will very careful about using the kind of keywords about memory. 

I feel disturbing you much more but one last question.
So why the local pickerView instance is not free up when viewDidLoad finished? Still i'm interacting with my pickerview even if its freed up?
I have a idea, perhaps the addsubview method keeps copy of my pickerView?

Comment: Is viewController lifecycle mechanism does arc when viewdisappear method called? 
Thanks...

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you push a new view controller on a navigation controller, for example, the view will disappear and `viewDid/WillDisappear` will be called, but the view controller is still in the stack, so it is still in memory. The view controller will be released when you pop the view controller off the stack.  It is in this case that you would have a leak if you had a circular strong reference.

Comment: Thank you so much. The point is the "circular" strong reference case. Understand more well. Thank you so much. I hope i will experience some memory leaks in kind of big apps in near future to fix them!

Comment: The picker view isn't released because you have added it as a subview of your view, so the view holds a strong reference to it.